# Debug a Go routine in Intellij

Tags: go, intellij-idea

Hi I hava a following Golang program which contain a Go Routine.

```
   func main() {
    go func(){
        fmt.Println("Break Point 1")
    }()
       fmt.Println("Break Point 2") 
       time.Sleep(100 * time.Second)
       fmt.Println("hello")
}
```

Now my program doesn't break at breakpoint 1. How do I debug routines also?

Answer (score 2):

```
func main() {
    go func() {
        fmt.Println("Break Point 1")
    }()
    fmt.Println("Break Point 2")
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("hello")
}
```

It seems like before the go routine gets scheduled the program terminates and that is the reason the breakpoint is not reached. Can you try adding sleep in main routine?

Comment: even after adding sleep, it has similar behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be using wait groups, which can help you wait until your routine finishes up. wg.Wait() in main will ask main to wait until all wait groups are done. in your go function add wg.Add(1) and at the end perform wg.Done().